# Root cause and retry of "The request was aborted because there was no available instance." error in Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

Over time, we see sometimes bursts of errors in our Cloud Functions - "The request was aborted because there was no available instance." with HTTP response 500, which indicates Cloud Functions intrinsically cannot manage the rate of traffic.
This happens for Cloud Functions triggered by changes on Firestore, RTDB, PubSub and even scheduled functions.
According to the [troubleshooting guide](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#scalability), this can happen due to sudden increase of traffic, long cold-starts or long request processing.
We also understand that it's a good practice to use exponential backoff retry mechanism where it's important that the Cloud Function will execute.
We know it's not a max-instance issue as we didn't set one for these functions, and also the error is 500 and not 429.

Questions:

1. Can we identify the underling root-cause - e.g. is it a cold-start? is it a long running function which causes it?
2. When functions fail due to cold-start time? Does this cold-start include only the time it takes to provision the instance and put the code there or also the initial execution of the runtime environment (e.g. `node index.js`), which executes also the code in the global scope?
3. Cloud Function have a [retry on failure configuration](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries#using_the). Does it cover also the "no available instance" case we experienced?

Comment: This question appears to be server related, not a coding question. I am sure it's frustrating but unfortunately there is very little we can do help here on SO. Questions posted here should be about a specific coding issue, including the code and troubleshooting. The question would probably be better suited for serverfault or possibly reddit. If you are seeing this frequently a great resource is the [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support). Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Itsik Belson I have provided an answer below.please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can be caused by one of the following:

- A huge sudden increase in traffic.
- A long cold start time.
- A long request processing time.
- Transient factors attributed to the Cloud Run service

As mentioned in this [github](https://github.com/ahmetb/cloud-run-faq#how-can-i-tell-if-a-request-was-a-cold-start),Cloud Run does not mark request logs with information about whether they caused a cold start or not.However,Stackdriver which is a suite  of monitoring tools (Stackdriver Logging,Stackdriver Error reporting,Stackdriver  Monitoring)  that helps you understand what is going on in your cloud functions. It has in-built tools for logging,reporting errors and monitoring.Apart from stackdriver, you can do execution times, execution counts and memory usage in the GCP console You can refer this [Stackdriver Logging and Stackdriver Trace for Cloud Functions](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-function-logs-traces#0) & [Error Reporting](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs)

cold-start includes the time it takes to provision the instance and also the initial execution of the runtime environment. I think the retry on failure configuration does not cover the "no available instance"

I have found this [github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/962) & [Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/194948300) raised for a similar issue which is still open.If you are still facing the issue, you can follow that issue for future updates and also add your concerns there.